# Laravel Save ssh Connection to use it again

Tags: laravel, ssh, laravelcollective

I am working on a system that setup ssh connection remotely to another server, to get resources  usage  info like (CPU, ram, disk ), I am able to get these detail  through an ssh connection, but my  problem is I want to get CPU usage every 5 sec, to show it on my  system, but every request the system creates a new connection to the server,  are there any ways  to  save my connection so I can use that connection again in the other requests, I am using the collective package to ssh in my server

Comment: The way PHP works is by basically destroying all resources created at the end of each request. You can have a persistent connection to the server that polls and returns the result every 5 seconds and keep that connection alive however if you are using PHP-FPM the webserver will probably terminate the connection after the specified timeout period of a request. Another way would be to use websockets between front-end and backend and again have the backend establish and maintain the SSH connection. There are many more approaches as well. Its not clear what would work best for you

Comment: thanks  for reply , so u suggest to use websocket , ok maybe I can have try with node js

Answer (score 0):

take a look at this [Laravel Envoy](https://github.com/laravel/envoy) package

Comment: thank you for reply , but this package seems to run task in queue,and it running the commands without returning  the output of it